# Can't manually share an account that is owned by a user below me in the role hierarchy

Tags: sharing, manual-sharing

One of my SFDC users needs to manually share an Account record with someone below them in the Role Hierarchy. The sharing button is not visible for this user on this Account record.

I was under the assumption that users higher in the role hierarchy than an Account owner, can manually share those records with other users.

Is this not the case?

Comment: check that `Sharing` button exists in Page Layout

Comment: Checked that. The sharing button does exist in the page layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, manual sharing is available for the record owner, any role in the hierarchy above the record owner, and the system admin.

From [Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_securing_data_manual_sharing_try_it_out.htm)  , *`You might not see the button if you’re not logged in as the candidate record owner` or system administrator. The button is available when your organization-wide default for candidates is set to Private or Public Read Only.*

So you might have confirmed that the `sharing` button is available when you logged in as admin. Try going to `Manage Users|Users` and login as the requesting user, or ask him to confirm that he can see the sharing button.

If the sharing button is not available, make sure that `Manual User Record Sharing` in `Sharing Settings` is checked.